# Header with different color from body using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Header and body using ConstraintLayout
Hi !
I would make a simple layout
[image: https://ibb.co/mBQvhD5]

Header should be of a different color from Body, and I want a shadow between header and body (body should be elevate).

Make it with linear layout is soo simple, but I can't do it with constraintLayout.. Can you help me ? I'm studying constraint and it is not soo easy for me ..

Some other details:

1. the header will stick
2. the recycler view will be covering all
   the space other than header view but with a left and right margin
3. i don't undestand how can I divide the section, with linear layout I
   would have created an external linearLayout with vertical
   orientation. Inside that I would have created a container at top
   with a given background and an elevation, with matchparent height
   (some dp), under that I would have created another linearLayout
   match parent , match parent. Inside this last linear layout I would
   have inserted a recycler view with a margin left and right

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then as per that you will make something like this:

TextView : **id: tvTopHeader** - *Header and body using ConstraintLayout Hi ! I would make a simple layout* 
View : id: divider1

TextView : **id: tvHeader** - *Header*
View: id: divider2

TextView : **id: tvBody** - *Body*
View: id: divider3

Now having the layout-width = "match_parent" and layout-height ="wrap_content" or some fixed value as per requirement...the constraints will be something like the following:

```
tvTopHeader: constraintTopToTopOf = "parent"
divider1: constraintTopToBottomOf ="@id/tvTopHeader"

tvHeader : constraintTopToBottomOf = "@id/divider1"
divider2: constraintTopToBottomOf ="@id/tvHeader"

tvBody : constraintTopToBottomOf = "@id/divider2"
divider3: constraintTopToBottomOf ="@id/tvBody"
```

Edit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With Linearlayout I would have get the goal in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title">
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="press"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Maybe using the constraint layout in this case is not the best ? But why ? I supposed that the constraint layout would replace all the other layout types.*

Comment: Hi ! Thanks :)
This layout is a header with some components: text view and buttons
And a body that contains a recycler view and some buttons

I have to set up different color for the header, moreover I have to set an elevation for the header block.

With linear layout I would have created two linear layouts I would have set up an elevation and background for the linear layout. 
But in constraint layout google suggest to not use other nested layout or i'm wrong ?

Comment: @aeroxr1 yes i dont think in this case you need any other layout container. Constraint Layout is enough. Leaving the elevation/color part as its the same as usual. Just need a little more clarification before i suggest something. 
1. The header here will stick or scroll with recycler view?
2. The recycler view will be covering all the space other than header view?
3. What difficulty are you facing in changing the elevation and bg color?. 

if possible upload a reference image of what design u need to implement

Comment: 1- the header will stick
2- the recycler view will be covering all the space other than header view but with a left and right margin
3- because i don't undestand how can I divide the section, with linear layout I would have created an external linearLayout with vertical orientation. Inside that I would have created a container at top with a given background and an elevation, with matchparent height (some dp), under that I would have created another linearLayout match parent , match parent. Inside this last linear layout I would have inserted a recycler view with a margin left and right

Comment: I have edited the first post with an image of the layout that i want implement

Comment: Hi !
I have tested your layout, but the elevation is only on the title and for that the shadow is only under that. 
I want the shadow appear under the @+id/view, is possible ? I want use the shadow to separate the recycler view to the top header ;)

Comment: its easy. Either you make a container view for the title and buttons and give elevation to the container or make a shadow view and use that as a separator from title and recycler view. Also a request, if this is working for you, kindly mark it as  asnwer.

Comment: I'm wondering if is acceptable for Android guideline to insert other container layout (maybe another constraint layout) inside a constraintlayout

Comment: why not?, sometimes we do need one constraint layout inside another just for ease of ux design. Eg: You want to give shadow to the whole container box that has multiple views, or you want to hide/show a group of view. And if there is some guideline like this please share it. I am not aware of any such guideline.

Comment: @aeroxr1 doing the layout design in your way, what will happen when your title is longer, and your screen width is smaller. Using constraints, you can use chain style and `app:layout_constrainedWidth` which will adjust the distance for all types of displays.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_header"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view2"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_body"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="Body"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view3"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_body"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output of above code is:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

Comment: mmm... I have edited the first post :D
In the header section I have to show two text view and the background color is blu
In the body section I have to show a recycler view and the background color is red
The header container is elevated of 5 dp